# iTextSharp TextRenderInfo.GetFillColor() and TextRenderInfo.GetStrokeColor() sometimes return null?

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm trying to get text color while parsing a PDF using iTextSharp. The issue is that sometimes the methods TextRenderInfo.GetFillColor() and TextRenderInfo.GetStrokeColor() return null. Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if no color has explicitly been set for filling or stroking respectively.

In that case the PDF specification has a default:

> **color space**
>   - name or array -
>   The *current colour space* in which colour values shall beinterpreted (see 8.6, "Colour Spaces"). There are two separate colour space parameters: one for stroking and one for all other painting operations. Initial value: **DeviceGray**.
>
> **color**
>   - (various) -
>   The *current colour* to be used during painting operations (see 8.6, "Colour Spaces"). The type and interpretation of this parameter depend on the current colour space; for most colour spaces, a colour value consists of one to four numbers. There are two separate colour parameters: one for stroking and one for all other painting operations. Initial value: black.

*(ISO 32000-1 Table 52 – Device-Independent Graphics State Parameters)*

Thus, if you get a null filling or stroking color, you can interpret it as *grayscale black*.